# If $g:X\to Y$ be a one-to-one correspondence and $X$ is finite, then $Y$ is finite too.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

> ***Corollary.*** Let $g:X\longrightarrow Y$ be a one-to-one correspondence. If the set $X$ is finite, then $Y$ is finite.
>
> *Proof.* Exercise.

Book :"Set Theory With Applications" by You-Feng Lin and Shwu Yeng T.Lin.

**My try:**
We know we have a one-to-one correspondence as:
$$g:X→Y$$
And also we can define a function as:
$$f:X→X$$
So :$$g∘f∘g^{-1}:Y→Y$$
We have:
$$g∘f∘g^{-1}(Y)=g∘f(X)$$
$$=g(f(X))$$
And because X is not Dedekind infinite so $f(X)=X$ and:
$$g(f(X))=g(X)=Y$$
**And by the way**:
$$g∘f∘g^{-1}(Y)=Y$$
So Y is finite.

Is that correct?

Comment: A set X is infinite provided that it has a proper subset Y such that there exists a one-to-one correspondence between X and Y. **A set is finite if it is not infinite.**By Dedekind definition as I mentoined in the question ;) @ashK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you don't need repeat the proof of Theorem 2 of your textbook's chapter titled "Denumerable & Nondenumerable sets" which says that "Let $g:X \to Y$ be an one-to-one correspondence. If $X$ is infinite, then $Y$ is infinite".

Suppose you have $g:X\to Y$ an one-to-one correspondence and $X$ is finite. If $Y$ was infinite, then $g^{-1}:Y\to X$ is an one-to-one corrrespondence and as a consequence of Theorem 2, $X$ must be infinite which would contradict our assumption. Hence, $Y$ must be finite.

Comment: Thanks.I needed this.